# With .NET DataContractSerializer instance, can I check the Type that was passed into its constructor?

Tags: .net, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

I'm specifically asking about `DataContractSerializer`, but this is also relevant to `XmlSerializer`

The constructors for these serializer types take a `Type` object as an argument, and each serializer instance can only serialize objects of this type.

Is there any way to later check this type?  There are no obvious `get` properties or methods that do this.

---

I am ultimately trying to create an extension method on `DataContractSerializer` to simplify serializing objects as XML to in-memory strings.

For this extension method, checking the type isn't mission critical, but I think it would allow for clearer exception handling.  If the check is left off the user will just get a `SerializationException` rather than an `ArguemntException`.

```
public static string WriteObjectToString(this DataContractSerializer serializer, object obj) {
    if (serializer == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializer));
    if (obj == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));

    //---------------------------
    //This statement will not compile:
    if (serializer.TypeToSerialize != obj.GetType()) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type.");
    //---------------------------

    using (var output = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(output)) {
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
        return output.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }        
}
```

---

A somewhat related question:

Is there a reason why `DataContractSerializer` (which was created after generics were introduced to .NET, unlike `XmlSerializer`) uses a `Type` object parameter rather than a generic type?  Wouldn't it be simpler to have a `DataContractSerializer{T}` with methods like

- `void WriteObject(Stream, T)`
- `T ReadObject(Stream)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is incorrect.  DataContractSerializer can serialize different types of objects when you pass in knownTypes in its constructor.  However, the resulting xml will use the first type name as its root xml element name.

The sample code below should work:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo), new Type[] {typeof(Bar), });
Bar bar = new Bar();
serializer.WriteObject(stream, bar);
```

The resulting XML will look like this:

```
<Foo><Bar>...</Bar></Foo>
```

Hope this information will change your design, because it is not necessary to create a DataContractSerializer object per type.  But it should explain why generic is not used with DataContractSerializer.

Comment: So if I create a serializer like this: `var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo))` and later I want to serialize an instance of `Bar` with it like this `s.WriteObject(myStream, myBar)`, will it serialize the `Bar` inside "foo" tags?  Will this deserialize property?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.  The deserialization will work as long as the serializer is constructed the same way.

Comment: Thank you.  The DataContract serialization API is so concise, I keep over thinking it.